# CCMask and threads

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, nsthread, kobold2d

I am using [Gilles Lesire's CCMask class](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15890) in my Kobold2d 2.0.3 (cocos2d-iphone v2.0 and OpenGL ES 2.0) game, but calling "createMaskForObject:withMask:" I get the following error:

-[CCRenderTexture initWithWidth:height:pixelFormat:depthStencilFormat:] : cocos2d: WARNING. CCRenderTexture is running on its own thread. Make sure that an OpenGL context is being used on this thread!

I don't really understand how to work with threads/opengl, but I was hoping someone would know how to fix this.

Comment: Can anybody help me out? I really need this solved! Thank you!

Comment: I have finally uploaded my code in a GIT. Feel free to improve. https://github.com/KingIsulgard/Cocos2D-CCMask-class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see this as well for cocos2d 2.0.  I don't think there is anything to fix.  If you look at line 81 of CCRenderTexture.m you will see:

```
if( [director runningThread] != [NSThread currentThread] )
```

If that is false, the warning is given.

But, if you're creating textures before the game/app is running, the background thread for CVDisplayLink doesn't look like it has been created yet. [director runningThread] (the thread for the CVDisplayLink) returns nil.  So that "if" statement will always be false.